# Product and sum of iid random variables converges a.s.

Tags: probability, independence, law-of-large-numbers, pointwise-convergence

The set of independent and identically distributed r.v. $Y_{1},Y_{2},...,Y_{n}$ has a distribution $Pr(Y_i=1)=Pr(Y_i=1/2)=1/2\ \forall i>0$ . If $Z_n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$ and $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_i \ \forall n>0$. Does $Sn$ converge a.s. to some limit r.v.? If so, find the mean and variance of the limit r.v.

I used the properties of iid r.v. to rewrite Sn as following: $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}Y_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_1)^{n}=(Y_1)+(Y_1)^{2}+...+(Y_1)^{n}.$$

According to the distribution, Yi=1 or Yi=1/2 but I am not sure how to implement that fact here. Moreover, the Law of Large Numbers and a.s. convergence involve the sum of r.v., so I don't know if they can apply here as well.

Comment: Try computing the mean and variance, that would be a start. Also how much do you know about martingales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $S_n - S_{n-1} = Z_n$. Use this to show that $S_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2$, thus $S_n$ has an $L^2$ limit $S_{\infty}$. Then $S_n$ must converge to $S_{\infty}$ almost surely along some subsequence. But since $S_n$ is a monotonic sequence, convergence along a subsequence implies convergence for the entire sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to get the inequality using the triangle inequality $\left| Y_1^{n} \right|\lt \left| \frac{Y_1(Y_1^{n}-1)}{(Y_1-1)} \right|+\left| \frac{-Y_1(Y_1^{n-1}-1)}{(Y_1-1)} \right| \lt \varepsilon$ but I do not know how to proceed from here, any idea?

Comment: What you need to bound is the expectation of $Z_n^2 = \prod_{i=1}^n Y_i^2$. By independence $\mathbb E[Z_n^2] = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[Y_i^2] = \mathbb E[Y_1^2]^n$. But since $\mathbb E[Y_1^2] < 1$, $\sqrt{\mathbb E[Z_n^2]}$ is summable thus showing $S_n$ is a Cauchy sequence

Comment: But Sn and Zn are not bounded by themselves. Actually, they are going to infinity.

Comment: $Z_n$ is though, $Z_n$ is bounded by 1. $S_n$ is not bounded but the typical behaviour of $Z_n$ is to decrease geometrically hence will have a finite sum.